# Wordpress 500 internal server error when changed site address in dashboard > settings

Tags: wordpress

I have not imagined the problem would be this big. Everything is going fine then I changed the permanent site address for the sake of SEO. From then 500 internal server error is displayed even for wp-admin login page. Please help me, I have tried changing .htaccess file also but no use.

Comment: Enable the define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); in config file first then it will display the exact error

Comment: Did you update the link inside the database?

Comment: No not in the database only in Dashboard> Settings I have updated. Both site URL and Wordpress URL I have changed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you have change the site URL.

The wordpress URL is saved in database, to change it you have to follow this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

start with add this to your wp-config.php

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
 define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

After that you could be able to reach your dashboard to change the site URL.

Hope that helped you.

Comment: Thank you, It helped me to reach admin page but even if I entered correct login credentials it's showing error what to do.

Comment: What are the different types of error? 
Can you tell me more? :)

Comment: You can change the URL directly in the DB as the define function in the wp-config.php has always been temperamental to me.

In wp_options in your WPDB you'll need to search for home and site_url. Change these two values to your new site URL.

You can do this in PHPMyAdmin